# Unzip huge file ( ~80 GB )- Using Java or shell script

Tags: java, linux, bash, file-io, gzip

I have a Java application from which I need to unzip GZIP files of about 80 GB . Should I go for unzip using Java API or should I call a bash script which unzips the file ? Which one will be efficient? I may have more than 1 zip files and therefore can I use multiple threads for each unzip? My environment is Linux based

Comment: Use Java API or bash script? *Primarily opinion-based.* --- Efficient? *Try it and see for yourself.* --- Multiple threads? *Yes.*

Answer (score 1):

`gunzip` command is faster than a Java-based unzip method because it's native code, highly optimized.

You could unzip each file in a separate process using bash, it would probably be faster, but not as faster as you could expect because of the disk access bottleneck.

Of course the bottleneck, although still here, is minimized in case of an SSD drive or unzipping several files in parallel on separate disks.

Comment: For files of that size, it might actually be slower to run multiple unzip in parallel, since it may increase disk arm seek times, assuming CPU is fast enough to keep disk busy with just one unzip in progress.

Comment: @Andreas depends if you're using a SSD drive (no arm involved, only transfer rate bottleneck) or unzipping in parallel in several drives (source files are on separate drives). The solution would need proper benchmarking anyway.